# How to filter records from DB based on user access rights

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I am building a REST service for an event management application.
The idea is that each user can see on the feed only events he has been invited to and events he created. One condition is that each user have multiple emails. 
What would be the best way to retrieve events (through JpaRepository) for a specific (authenticated) user?

One possible solution I thought of is having a query like the following, where :auth_email and :auth_id is the email and id of authenticated user.

```
SELECT e.* FROM events e 
  WHERE e.user_id = :auth_id OR
  EXISTS (
    SELECT id FROM invitations 
      WHERE (e.id = invitations.event_id) AND
       (
        invitations.email = :auth_email 
        OR EXISTS (
          SELECT id FROM user_emails WHERE
            (user_emails.user_id = :auth_id) 
            AND (invitations.email = user_emails.email)
        )
      )
  )
```

I'm not sure if it's scalable and also I'm not sure how to "translate" it to JPQL...

Approximate models I have:

1. USERS table used for authentification, contains primary email

```
@Data @Entity @Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    // other columns
}
```

2. USER_EMAILS - used to keep additional (personal) user emails:

```
@Data @Entity @Table(name = "user_emails")
public class UserEmails {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
}
```

3. EVENTS

```
@Data @Entity @Table(name = "events")
public class Event {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id") @JsonIgnore
    private List<Invitation> invitations;

    private String title;
    // other columns
}
```

4. INVITATIONS - users (emails) invited to an event - can be used primary email (users.email) or any personal email (from user_emails)

```
@Data @Entity @Table(name = "invitations")
public class Invitation {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String email;

    @ManyToOne @JsonIgnore
    private Event event;
}
```

Comment: *"How to filter records from DB based on user access rights"* Consider using PostgreSQL instead which has native [Row Security Policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-rowsecurity.html) for RDMS user accounts and application users..   MySQL does not have such thing ..

Comment: If it were me, I'd probably not keep the primary e-mail in the user record. Rather, I'd keep it with the rest of the user's e-mails, and just put its ID in the user's record as "primary" for cases when you need to access it.

Comment: But it should be possible in MySQL to simulate PostgreSQL Row Security Policies with a VIEW and a function on the MariaDB (blog) website there was somewhere a example / explainment..

Comment: @RaymondNijland don't confuse database user access privileges with customer information. The user in question probably doesn't authenticate themselves directly to the database anyway.

Comment: *"don't confuse database user access privileges with customer information. The user in question probably doesn't authenticate themselves directly to the database anyway."* @RealSkeptic i didn't confuse that noticed i said *"for RDMS user accounts and **application users.**"* in mine first comment..

Comment: Spring data supports SPEL-expression like ```@Query("select e from UserEmails e where e.user.id = ?#{principal.id}")```

Comment: .. also i was also talking about this @RealSkeptic [Protect Your Data: Row-level Security in MariaDB 10.0](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/protect-your-data-row-level-security-in-mariadb-10-0/) to simulate [PostgreSQL Row Security Policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-rowsecurity.html) in MySQL/MariaDB.. That code can be easy changed to check application users aswell and filter for application users also and simulate PostgreSQL's Row Security Policies which also have that support..